# Keyboard freezes after input does not find result

Tags: swift, xcode, keyboard

When the return key is pressed on the keyboard, it should trigger the button action. While this does work, if nothing is found the keyboard freezes and the user cannot type anything else. What can I do about this?

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    londonButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

The action associated with the londonButton is

```
@IBAction func londonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    searchit()
}

func searchit() {
    pulsePow()
    city = search.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
```

Comment: Can you show the `sendActions` method?

Comment: Take a look at what I've added